# Question on creating SPF record for the first time and trying not to disrupt mail delivery

Tags: spf

I'm creating an SPF record for our domain.  We never had one before.  I've been collecting DMARC reports so I have a good idea what IPs we are using to send email and I have a good idea what additional "includes" we need.  Since we don't have an SPF record at the moment, some ISPs are flagging our mail but it's still being delivered.  My question is this:  If I terminate my SPF record with ~all and I missed some IPs or includes, will we be any worse off than we were when we had no SPF record?

My goal here is to minimize any email delivery disruptions as we work through the implementation of SPF DMARC and DKIM.  At some point we will change the ~all to -all but for now I have to be cautious as to not disrupt email delivery.  From what I have read, using ~all should be a safeguard against missing a network or a host.  Just wanted to be sure about this before I activate the SPF record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're using SPF *with* DMARC, you should only go as far as `~all` anyway; you can configure DMARC to report everything that does not obtain a `pass` status, including softfails. The way to phase it in is to configure your services to sign everything with DKIM, set your DMARC to `pct=100`, saying that receivers should expect everything to be signed, configure your `ruf` and `rua` parameters so that you get to hear about any delivery problems, and then set `p=none`. This will allow you to see any problems. Leave it like tat for a while and see if anything is reported, then when you're ready set `p=quarantine`, and ultimately `p=reject`. You do need to be absolutely sure of all your mail sources before you can get to that point though.